# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee]

Tags: xml, spring, maven, flume

I got the following error:

```
2014-06-30 15:14:08,089 ERROR [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run:160)  - Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee]
Offending resource: class path resource [beans/esb-message.xml]
```

The header of esb-message.xml is:

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"       
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"          
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```

As I understand, it is basically missing the NamespaceHandler for jee. As I search online, The JeeNamespaceHandler is in spring-context.jar. I have that jar in my maven-lib. But why I still get that error?

Answer (score 0):

What version of spring-context.jar did you use? Did you have duplicate version of spring-schemas.jar? Expand the jar and see if there's a `META-INF/spring.schemas` file inside with following content:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
```